# Searching a vector, then displaying the next element in a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

```
void encodeFunc (char ch, vector<string>& keyAlpha); 

int main(){
    ch = msgContent.at(i);
    encodeFunc(ch, keyAlpha);
}

void endcodeFunc (char ch, vector<string>& keyAlpha){
        typedef vector<string> keyCheck;
        typedef keyCheck::const_iterator keyIterator;
        keyIterator q = find(keyAlpha.begin(), keyAlpha.end(), ch);
        int element = distance(keyAlpha.begin(), q);
        cout << keyAlpha.at(element+1);

    }
```

I  have the above bits of code to find a given `char` in a vector, and then display the next element in the vector. However, when attempting to search for `ch`, which is populated by the statement `ch = msgContent.at(i);` , I receive the error `[Error] no matching function for call to 'distance(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, keyIterator&)'`

Is this a pointer issue that I'm not picking up on, or is there something more?

Comment: typedef vector<string>::const_iterator keyIterator; or simply use c++11     auto q=find(keyAlpha.begin(), keyAlpha.end(), ch);

Comment: keyAlpha is an vector of string so you can not use find to find a character.

Comment: First suggestion gives the same error;

Second suggestion gives a different error: `[Error] 'q' does not name a type`

I've never used `auto` before, is there another library I need to include to use it?

Answer (score 2):

You have typedef'd `keyIterator` to be a `vector<string>::const_iterator`. The problem is that `keyAlpha.begin()` returns a `vector<string>::iterator`, so you're passing two different types to `std::distance`, which causes the template type deduction to fail.

You probably want:

```
int element = distance(keyAlpha.cbegin(), q);
```

`cbegin()` returns a `const_iterator`.

As a side note, a much simpler way of doing this is just:

```
void endcodeFunc(const string& ch, const vector<string>& keyAlpha)
{
    auto it = find(keyAlpha.cbegin(), keyAlpha.cend(), ch);
    if (it != keyAlpha.cend() && (it + 1) != keyAlpha.cend())
        cout << *(it + 1);
}
```

Comment: keyAlpha is an vector of string so ypu can not use find to find a char.

Comment: @user1438832, fixed.